# Rewirte old URLs to new URLs via Apache Rewrite Rule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

We have recently migrated to new a platform, the new site is pointing to the domain `droidnews.net` and the old site is pointing to the domain `droidnews.cc`

We now want to redirect all old URL requests to the new site/domain.

```
www.droidnews.net/articles/2012/07/18/227063.html
to
www.droidnews.cc/articles/2012/07/18/227063.html
```

Answer (score 0):

This Apache rewrite rule should work fine:

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.droidnews\.net [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
  RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://www.droidnews.cc/$1 [L,R=303]
```

Answer (score 0):

To redirect all requests to the new domain `droidnews.net`, you can use [`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect)

```
Redirect / http://www.droidnews.net/
```